# VB.NET split on new lines (C# conversion)

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, split

I'm trying to convert this code from C# to VB.NET

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Here's what I have, the problem is it is printing the whole of the text box contents in the messagebox, instead of each line.

```
    Dim Excluded() As String

    Dim arg() As String = {"\r\n", "\n"}

    Excluded = txtExclude.Text.Split(arg, StringSplitOptions.None)

    For i As Integer = 0 To Excluded.GetUpperBound(0)
        MessageBox.Show("'" & Excluded(i) & "'")
    Next
```

Comment: Did you try an online converter? It gives me `Dim lines As String() = theText.Split(New String() {vbCr & vbLf, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape sequences don't really exist in VB .Net as far as string literals are concerned.

There are 2 special constants which you can use instead:

`vbCrLf`
`vbLf`

```
Dim Excluded() As String

Dim arg() As String = {vbCrLf, vbLf}

Excluded = txtExclude.Text.Split(arg, StringSplitOptions.None)

For i As Integer = 0 To Excluded.GetUpperBound(0)
    MessageBox.Show("'" & Excluded(i) & "'")
Next
```

Should do the trick (untested though).

Comment: Little mistake: vbCrLf is equivalent to C# "\r\n", but vbNewLine is platform dependant. On a Windows platform (would be different if run on Linux through mono for instance), vbNewLine is also equivalent to "\r\n". So this code is not strictly equivalent to the C# version: "\n" will never be caught! Use vbLf or ControlChars.Lf

Comment: @odalet: This is odd.. how can a const be platform-dependent, actually? It could only represent the compile-time platform, not the run-time platform. Turns out it doesn't, it's equal to `vbCrLf`, even on mono: https://github.com/mono/mono-basic/blob/master/vbruntime/Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft.VisualBasic/Constants.vb

Comment: @noah1989: You're right; in the mono case, it appears vbNewLine = \r\n. I suppose the mono team made the choice to favor language compatibility over OS conventions. Anyway, according to MSDN, vbNewline represent just a "new line", not a clearly specified string. Though unlikely, its real value may change depending on platforms or implementations. vbCrLf should never change.

Comment: @noah1989: And concerning the general case of a platform-dependant const, it is easily achievable be using #if preprocessor instructions... Scroll a bit in the mono vb runtime source code and you'll notice that some constants are not defined in the moonlight case. Same constructs could be used to set a different value to a constant depending on the target platform.

Comment: @noah1989: sorry for spamming, but interestingly enough, it appears that vbNewLine was platform dependant back to the VBScript days: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh277t8e.aspx

Comment: @odalet: Of course you can use preprocessor instructions. But the same compiled .net assembly can be executed on different platforms -- vbNewLine, being a const, could not change after compilation, so it cannot be runtime-platform-dependent. Making it dependent on the compile-time platform would be rather silly, though. furthermore, since it's actually defined in a framework dll, using #if would make it depend on the platform the runtime used at compile time was itself compiled on...

Comment: @noah1989: Agreed, a const is a const once compiled. But one source code can be compiled to target different platforms: Silverlight's mscorlib.dll is not the same as desktop .NET's one. And #if doesn't make it depend on the compilation machine platform, but on the configuration (the target platform) you decide to use at compile time. That's cross-compilation. This is similar to how you can generate different code based on the debug or release configuration or to distinguish between x86 and x64

Comment: @odalet also agreed, but cross-compiling .NET assemblies would be rather sick, wouldn't it? Using the same binaries on all platforms is the whole point of IL and JIT. (yeah I know there is that x86/x64 thing, but that's just metadata that tells the runtime which kind of process to create in case you need that for COM interop and such, the IL code stays the same.)

Comment: @noah1989: interop is exactly the scenario I have in mind. I happen to regularly write platform-dependant code in .NET; each time you need operate a device, integrate a native lib or just write fancy Windows Forms controls, you are likely to face the x86/x64 problems.

Comment: @odalet: that's a point indeed, there's no almost way around platform-dependent binaries when doing such things but I doubt someone would do such hassle for a newline instead of using the runtime-evaluated `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 9):

You can't use backslash (`\`) to escape characters in VB. Use the `ControlChars` class:

```
Dim arg() As String = { ControlChars.CrLf, ControlChars.Lf }
```

Comment: +1 for using `ControlChars` instead of the old VB6-style constant names. :)

Comment: yes vb.net don't have escape characters, so you have to use these special characters.

Answer (score 2):

From an [online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/):

Your c# code:

`string[] lines = theText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Converted to VB.NET:

```
Dim lines As String() = theText.Split(New String() {vbCr & vbLf, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```