# Prevent the `vbLf` being included in a `String.Length` calculation

Tags: vb.net, text, split, trim

I have a `Collection` of servers which I take from a multiline textbox.

I have some simple validation which should be trimming whitespace (to prevent an entry being created for blank line), but it's not working.

For example, if `Me.formServers.txtServers.Text` is as follows, the lengths of the lines are returned as 5, 5, 5 and 4. How can I correctly calculate the length of each line and thus avoid erroneous items being added to my `Collection`? Thanks.

> TTSA
>   TTSB
>   TTSC
>   TTSD

Here is my code

```
Me.Servers = New Collection ' Reset 'Servers' to ensure only the correct servers are included

For Each Server As String In Me.formServers.txtServers.Text.Split(vbLf)
    If Not Server.Trim.Length = 0 Then Me.Servers.Add(Server)
    MsgBox(Server.Length)
Next
```

Comment: Does it work properly if you split on `Environment.NewLine` rather than `vbLf`?

Comment: Unfortunately now. The lengths returned are now 4, 5, 5 and 5. Thanks.

Comment: `vbCrLf` is the same as `vbLf` - it splits the lines, but seems to be pushing the `vbLf` to the start of the next line. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET split on new lines (C# conversion)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408155/vb-net-split-on-new-lines-c-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

This test was interesting:

```
    Dim s As String = "TTSA" & vbCrLf
    s &= "TTSB" & vbLf
    s &= "TTSC" & vbCr
    s &= "TTSD" & Environment.NewLine
    s &= "TTSE" & vbNewLine

    Dim Excluded() As String
    Excluded = s.Split({vbCrLf, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    For Each s In Excluded
        Debug.Print(s & " " & s.Length)
    Next

    result:
    TTSA 4
    TTSB 4
    TTSC     ' vbCr was not in list so is still in the string
    TTSD 9
    TTSE 4
     0       ' last separator honored

     Corrected to:    
        Excluded = s.Split({vbCrLf, vbLf, vbCr}, _
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: You could simplify even further with `vbCrLf.ToCharArray`