# ControlChars Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hi I importing CSV file into SQL using vb.net
and right now I don't know what should i use of ControlChars Fields.

Whenever I used **ControlChars.Lf**

My sql script looks like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'47_8', N'NC56', N'J93
')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'61_3', N'NC60', N'F123
')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'63_8', N'NC61', N'J125
')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'16_7', N'ND8', N'B29
')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'29_1', N'ND9', N'F58
')
```

there's a newline at the end of the value.

While, Whenever I used **ControlChars.CrLf** and **ControlChars.Cr**

the script looks like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'
47_8', N'NC56', N'J93')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'
61_3', N'NC60', N'F123')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'
63_8', N'NC61', N'J125')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'
16_7', N'ND8', N'B29')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'
29_1', N'ND9', N'F58')
```

the new line is in the first value.

right now I dont know what **ControlChars Fields should I use** for this script:

```
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'47_8', N'NC56', N'J93')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'61_3', N'NC60', N'F123')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'63_8', N'NC61', N'J125')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'16_7', N'ND8', N'B29')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'29_1', N'ND9', N'F58')
```

**No new line** in every value of my datafields.

My VB.NET Codes:

```
Dim csvPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath)

Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(4) {New DataColumn("WireID", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("PadNo", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("CoaxSolid", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Pattern", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Tester", GetType(String))})

Dim csvData As String = File.ReadAllText(csvPath)
For Each row As String In csvData.Split(ControlChars.Cr)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row) Then
        dt.Rows.Add()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim wireid As Integer = ID.ToString
        For Each cell As String In row.Split(",")
            If i = 0 Then
                dt.Rows((dt.Rows.Count - 1))(i) = wireid
                dt.Rows((dt.Rows.Count - 1))(1) = cell
            Else
                dt.Rows((dt.Rows.Count - 1))(i + 1) = cell
            End If
            i += 1 
        Next
    End If
Next

Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStrX)
    Using sqlBulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(con)
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TblR8Mix"
        con.Open()
        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it.

Change this ..

```
For Each row As String In csvData.Split(ControlChars.Cr)
```

into this code:

```
For Each row As String In csvData.Split(ControlChars.CrLf, ControlChars.Lf)
```

[Refer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408155/vb-net-split-on-new-lines-c-conversion/6408222#6408222)

**Script OUTPUT:**

```
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'47_8', N'NC56', N'J93')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'61_3', N'NC60', N'F123')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'63_8', N'NC61', N'J125')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'16_7', N'ND8', N'B29')
INSERT [dbo].[TblR8Mix] ([WireID], [PadNo], [Pattern], [Tester]) VALUES (8, N'29_1', N'ND9', N'F58')
```